# Web publish is adding a namespaced connection string when deploying

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first, webdeploy

When using webpublish in visual studio 2012 with a code first migration context, I happen to have a problem. In our web.config, there is two connection strings, defined like so;

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="C2EnterpriseDB" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=C2_V5;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MediaProviderDB" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=C2_V5_Media;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>.
```

But when I open webpublish dialog, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs6Fb.jpg) is what is shown to me. Anybody can tell me why I have 3 connections strings instead of two like this  ?

Thanks

edit1: Might be onto something, if I remove the reference to my repository project (where i enabled migrations) I only get the 2 connections defined in my web.config. Makes any sense to you guys that a migration-enabled project would add its own connectionstring to the 2 already existing? I checked if any constrings were set in the app.config of that project.. but nope.

edit2: But then I can't "activate" migrations at deploy time, checkbox is disabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was having 2 web projects in my solution both pointing to the repository project where my migration was. So web-publish thought it was 2 different databases with the same name and created a namespaced one to differentiate the 2.

What I did for now is remove the web.config from one of my webproject, reference my other webproject from the first one and only point my Api webproject to the repository. There.